# randomize falling pattern of an array

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics, rigid-body-simulation, origin

I'm having some issues with the simulated animation from learning blender. specifically my arrays of 30mm vulcan bullets, they all fall too uniformly perfect. The tips come off all at same time and start to tilt in exact same direction before unrealistically landing in a pile.

separate by geometry, individual origin points.

I have asked, on blender.chat, Chamferzones youtube page, chamferzones discord, and have watch the tutorial like 5 times. His results are different. I have searched for arrays and gravity rigid body physics and cannot find anything useful.
This is an image at frame 5 or so as they begin to fall.
[image: falling simulation]

[image: Final still, eevee]

Blend file link. https://mega.nz/file/240WzRaB#QDcSKBo72B2QIzWfLsixIT8cQOKLWAL76VUJar8dGUg

I have never shared a blend file hopefully that works if not let me know how.
I packed external data and made relative just in case, not sure if i needed to though.

Comment: show us your blend file, an image does not help.

Comment: For objects that dense and only 5 frames, that's quite realistic. You could try adding a weak force field, as well as select one of the objects, and rotate and move it in the proportional editing - random mode.

Comment: I added the blend file to this question.

Comment: @Markus von Broady , you are the second to recommend a slight proportional edit. Easily doable and would work but the instructor did not do that. I'd like to know how am still waiting on his response. Also I found a related question where someone suggested dropping them through a funnel out of camera view so they bounce around a bit first. I can also see just dumping them from a bucket, or using a particle system to just pop one after another like they were coming from a Gatling gun. All idea work for end result but im just want to understand why his just fell random while mine are to uniform.

Comment: @chris sorry not used to the formatting here, posted blend file and edits, i got the end result that is good enough, just still curious if i missed something.

Answer (score 1):

in the rigid body section, change the collision shape from convex hull to Mesh.

[image]