# Rigid Body animation just falling (not colliding)

Tags: animation

I have followed this tutorial at the end of the video to a T and when I play the animation, the bullets just fall straight to the ground and land with literally no change. In the tutorial they start to "float" in different directions as they fall which makes them scatter once hitting the ground. I have all the settings exactly the same so no idea where I went wrong. Any ideas??? See photo of after I play the animation.

This is the tutorial. Fast forward to about 2 hours.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2U0MiZSV9A

[image]

Comment: Seems to be the same question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/211765/107598 the answer works but it's still a mystery why it doesn't work like in the tutorial video

Comment: Does this answer your question? [randomize falling pattern of an array](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211765/randomize-falling-pattern-of-an-array)